# WebGL not working on localhost

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, webgl, babylonjs

I've got Linux Mint 17.2 64bit and try to launch a Babylon.JS project.
When I look through examples on the BabylonJS site, all the graphics show up fine, but when loading my project, in the Console either in FF or in Chrome I get the "Webgl not supported" error. And this has nothing to do with my code, since the error happens on very initialization of BabylonJS on localhost (tested).

I use script src="http://cdn.babylonjs.com/2-2/babylon.js"

The appropriate changes for either browser in order to enable WebGL are done according to manuals.

Where should I look to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should look into all script files you are using and whether they are compatible with your system. I'm not sure, but I could guess that this has something to do with the particular environment the source script is running.

I had similar problem when trying to run [simple shader example](https://aerotwist.com/tutorials/an-introduction-to-shaders-part-1/). I copied all the same files, but apparently it did not work localhost while did on website.

I fixed the problem by requiring latest three js script instead of the one included on the website. That magically fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the trick was in the fact, that I tried to initialize the unexisting canvas (deleted by chance), so the question is solved.
Thanks everybody for the answers.

Answer (score -2):

As you said that "Webgl not supported", that means your browser is not support WEBGL. either it is FF or Chrome. Try to update the browser to latest build.

You should try this link for Google Chrome.

https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/3098656?rd=1

Comment: You should read the question more carefully. 
As he said, it DOES work on remote server, but does NOT when running on localhost.